# how to remove extra line break inside longtable after listing?

Tags: listings, longtable

I have one column specification set as `p{4in}` in a longtable. I keep getting an extra empty line in this column for some reason.

I use listing inside the column, since I need to break the listing inside the column. Everything works ok, except there is this extra blank line.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|p{4in}|}\hline
\#&ODE and type of ODE\\\hline
\hyperlink{subsection_1}{ODE 1}&$y'(x)=a f(x)$
\begin{lstlisting}
[_quadrature]
\end{lstlisting}
\\\hline
\hyperlink{subsection_2}{ODE 2}&$y'(x)=y(x)+x+\sin (x)$
\begin{lstlisting}
[[_linear, `class A`]]
\end{lstlisting}
\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Here is the PDF

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I need to have the math equation on one line, and below it a listing. But I do not need that extra empty line that shows below the listing.

I tried  `breaklines=false` for the listing options, but still get an empty line below the listing. If I remove the whole listing part, then the extra empty line goes away. So it seems a side effect of having the listing there?

tex live 2016.

Comment: @cfr I just tried it. It seemed to increase the spacing :(  still empty line below the listing. Tried different values `\\[-10\baselineskip]\hline` does not seem to have any effect. still empty line below listing. Thanks.

Comment: if you not use `array` package than works `\end{lstlisting}\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}\\ \hline`.

Comment: @Zarko great! That worked. Please feel free to post this as answer and will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that use of `lstlisting` in `longtable` is not straightforward ...

If you not use `array` package in document, than a rude solution is add `\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}  \\\hline` after the `end{lstlisting}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|p{4in}|}\hline
\#                              &   ODE and type of ODE \\  \hline
\hyperlink{subsection_1}{ODE 1} &   $y'(x)=a f(x)$
\begin{lstlisting}
[_quadrature]
\end{lstlisting}\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}  \\\hline
\hyperlink{subsection_2}{ODE 2}&$y'(x)=y(x)+x+\sin (x)$
\begin{lstlisting}
[_linear, `class A`]
\end{lstlisting}\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}  \\\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]