# adding array package changes vertical space in long table

Tags: listings, longtable, arrays

I need to put listings inside one of the columns in a long table. The actual longtable I have is more complicated, but I made a MWE below to show.

I am using the solution given in [how-to-remove-extra-line-break-inside-longtable-after-listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345960/how-to-remove-extra-line-break-inside-longtable-after-listing)  which works well in order to remove extra space that shows at bottom of listing inside table.

But once I include the `array` package then the above solution now no long works.

Will show a MWE, without using `array` first, which is what I want

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%ext    
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}    
\usepackage{longtable} %2/24/16  does not work in two columns
%\usepackage{array}  %uncomment to see the problem

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true}

\begin{document}     
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{3in}|}\hline 
 \vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}
 \begin{lstlisting}
this is code
which can be long
 \end{lstlisting}
 \vspace{-1.2\baselineskip} 
 \\\hline
%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}
 \begin{lstlisting}
this is also code
 \end{lstlisting}
 \vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}
 \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

now `lualatex foo.tex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when adding `array` package (which I need somewhere else in the document), the output becomes

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've looked at  answers to [why-does-longtable-not-process-medskip-inside-a-row-but-tabular-does](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413473/why-does-longtable-not-process-medskip-inside-a-row-but-tabular-does) since it seems related. it is about interaction between `array` and `longtable`. But I am not able after much trial and error figure how to use any of the solutions above in my code to make it not generate the extra space.

What I would like is to be able to include `array` package in the above MWE, but not have the extra space below the list pop up again.

Using TL 2018

File listings:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 amsmath.sty    2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
mathtools.sty    2018/01/08 v1.21 mathematical typesetting tools
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
   array.sty    2018/04/30 v2.4h Tabular extension package (FMi)
listings.sty    2018/09/02 1.7 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2018/09/02 1.7 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2018/09/02 1.7 listings configuration
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

**Update**

I tried the suggestion in the comment below, but I can't get it to work. May be I am not doing it correctly. Here is what I tried

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%ext    
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}    
\usepackage{longtable} %2/24/16  does not work in two columns
\usepackage{array}    
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true,
aboveskip= -0ex,
belowskip=-2ex
}

\listfiles
\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{3in}|}\hline 
\begin{minipage}{3in}
 \begin{lstlisting}
this is code
which can be long
and have more than one line
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
 \\\hline
%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}{3in}
 \begin{lstlisting}
this is also code
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
 \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

It gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without the mini-page being there, it gives this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%ext
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable} %2/24/16  does not work in two columns
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true,
aboveskip= -0ex,
belowskip=-2ex
}

\begin{document}     
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{3in}|}\hline 
 \begin{lstlisting}
this is code
which can be long
and have more than one line
 \end{lstlisting}
 \\\hline
%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{lstlisting}
this is also code
 \end{lstlisting}
 \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: meanwhile (from time when i wrote linked answer) the package `array` is changed (improved vertical spaces). consequently this time proposed solution doesn't work anymore. a possible solution: (i) to `\lstset` add `aboveskip= 0ex, belowskip=-2ex` and (ii) `lstlisting` enclose in `minipage`. with this the result be independent from presence of the `array` package.

Comment: @Zarko thanks. I am not able to get it to work. Once I put the listing inside a minipage, it does not expand vertically to fill the space as needed. I can't post the code here, as too large. May be I did not do it as it should be, so will add it to my question as additional part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

code is to long that i can put in comment ...

interestingly, if i copy your test and test it again, i can reproduce your result. however, my original test, where i use the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%ext
\usepackage{array, longtable}  % 2/24/16  does not work in two columns
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true,
keepspaces=true,
aboveskip= 0ex, 
belowskip=1ex  % <--- changed
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3in}|}
\hline
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% <--- changed in comparison to your code
\begin{lstlisting}
this is code
which can be long
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\\ \hline
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% <--- changed in comparison to your code
\begin{lstlisting}
this is also code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

i obtain the following result:

[image]

in code is now small difference (indicated by % <---). why i should change this, i can't explain ... maybe because i meanwhile upgrade my (two week old) `miktex` installation. before my test i delete `.aux` file.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to how `array` adds the struts at the beginning and end of a `p` column.

Rather than manually piling up instructions, I suggest to define a specific environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}    
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  breaklines=true
}

\lstnewenvironment{tablelstlisting}
 {\minipage{\linewidth}}
 {\endminipage}

\begin{document}     
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{3in}|}
\hline
\begin{tablelstlisting}
this is code
which can be long
\end{tablelstlisting}
\\
\hline
%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tablelstlisting}
this is also code
\end{tablelstlisting}
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach, if you want to get narrower top and bottom spacing:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}    
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  breaklines=true
}

\lstnewenvironment{tablelstlisting}
 {\mbox{}\vspace*{-1.2\baselineskip}}
 {\endgraf\mbox{}\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}     
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{3in}|}
\hline
\begin{tablelstlisting}
this is code
which can be long
\end{tablelstlisting}
\\
\hline
%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tablelstlisting}
this is also code
\end{tablelstlisting}
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]